# Sending single emails without being marked as spam

Tags: email, mailchimp, amazon-ses

I'm using my Google Apps account (Standard version) to send single emails (automatically) to real interested customers.

The problem is that my sender email account has been suspended, because it's been considered as a "spammer" by Google.

What can I do in order to send that kind of emails from now on? I use [MailChimp](http://www.mailchimp.com) to send massive emails, and I've seen it has an API, called [STS](http://apidocs.mailchimp.com/sts/), for sending single emails, but it also required an Amazon SES account, so I don't know whether to invest on those services or doing something else.

What do you recommend for this case?

Comment: Do you have an email account that has an smtp server?  Maybe through your isp or web site host?  If you do, you can send emails through that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try a service that specializes in sending "transactional" emails, such as [Sendgrid](http://sendgrid.com), [Postmarkapp](http://postmarkapp.com) and [Mailjet](http://mailjet.com).

They have APIs and libraries for most programming languages, but in your case you just need to configure the SMTP server they rovide in your email client and you're good to go. They help you not get into the spam folder of your recipients, and help make sure you don't get flagged as a spammer

With most of them you should get some prettty powerfull analytics as well, which is a nice bonus.

Comment: What about Mandrill (http://mandrill.com/) and Amazon SES (http://aws.amazon.com/ses/)? Have you heard about them? It seems cheaper, but I'm not sure if all I need to hire are those two services to be ready to go.

Comment: Neverheard about Mandrill, bu Amazon SES does provide an SMTP server, so it might do the trick for you

Comment: Thanks! I'll take your advise.